# If $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, then $f$ is not injective

Tags: real-analysis

Given a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and given that $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, how can I prove that $f$ is not injective (one to one)?

I tried to bound $f(x)$ by some positive $\varepsilon$ (when $x$ is positive), then bound it by a smaller epsilon in the other end (where $x$ is negative), so that $f(x)$ is contained in the larger bound. But I don't think it can get me far, because I can't point to specific $y$ and prove that it has different values of $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: What about the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to\pm\infty$? Doesn't look like you completed that sentence, so we're lacking information

Comment: Yes sorry, the limit is zero.

Comment: Then you could probably use that injective continuous functions are either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing

Comment: How far can you get yourself?

Comment: I tried to bound f(x) by some positive epsilon(when x is positive), then bound it by a smaller epsilon in the other end(where x is negative), so that f(x) is contained in the larger bound. But I don't think it can get me far. Because I can't point to specific y and prove that it has different values of x such that f(x)=y.

Answer (score 1):

One can assume that $y_0= f(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0 \in R$. ( If not then you look at $-f(x)$).  Also, since the limits of $f$ is $0$ on both ends and $f$ is continuous it follows that $f((-\infty,x_0))$ contains the segment $(0,y_0)$ and that $f((x_0,\infty))$ contains the same segment. Again, since $f$ is continuous it has intermittent value property, i.e. for any $y \in (0,y_0)$ there is an $x_l \in (-\infty,x_0)$ such that $y=f(x_l)$ and by the same reason there is $x_r \in(x_0,\infty)$ such that $y=f(x_r)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for a contradiction that $f$ was injective. As it is also continuous, it is then strictly monotone. Suppose without loss of generality that $f$ is strictly increasing. Pick a point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)\neq0$. Assume without loss of generality that $f(x_0)>0$. Let $M\in(0,f(x_0))$. Then, as $f$ is increasing, $f(x)>M$ for all $x>x_0$, but in particular this also means that

$$0=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\geq M>0,$$

which is a contradiction.